# background package with tikz externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, tikz-external

I'm trying to use a background image for the title page of a book using the `background` package. The book has many TikZ images and so I would like to use the TikZ `external` package.

It doesn't work: Sometimes I get a compile error, and sometimes it compiles but the background image just doesn't show up. (I suspect the difference has to do with stray commands in the `aux` files or something, but I can't seem to reproduce it.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,angle=0,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

The compile error that I (sometimes) get is:

```
./background-mwe-copy.tex:20: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdfla
tex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/backgrou
nd-mwe-copy-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{background-mwe-copy}\input{backg
round-mwe-copy}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/background-mwe-c
opy-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you ha
ve enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Someti
mes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command si
mply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/background-mwe-copy-figure0.l
og'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.20 \end{document}
```

(I *have* enabled system calls, via `-shell-escape` in TeXShop Preferences > Engine > pdfTeX > Latex.)

If I comment out `\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]`, it looks fine:

[image]

Comment: I would use eso-pic or with a new LaTeX the shipout/background hook to add a picture. Background  is rather overkill and as it uses tikz rather fragile.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This suggestion worked. If you post is as an answer, I'll accept it.