# problem with sectsty + eso-pic/background + \section on new page

Tags: sectioning, color, page-breaking, eso-pic, sectsty

The `.cls` file I am using uses the `sectsty` package to style the section headers. It also uses the `eso-pic` package to add a background picture. (It used to use the `background` package but I changed it to `eso-pic` following the advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594462/63847).) I defined a new environment called `remark`.

**When a `remark` ends a page *and* a `\section` command falls at the start of the next page, the compile crashes,** i.e., it hangs forever.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\color{blue}\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-1ex}{1pt}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{remark}{\vspace{0.5cm}}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\lipsum[6][1-3]

\begin{remark}%
\lipsum[1][1-6]
\end{remark}

\section{A New Section}

\end{document}
```

(I moved the relevant lines out of the `.cls` file directly into the MWE so it's all in one place. But in my actual document, the first 3 commands are in the `.cls`.)

When I compile the MWE, it hangs. However:

- If I comment out the `\section` command, it compiles.
- If I comment out the `\begin{remark}` and `\end{remark}`, it compiles.
- If I add more or less text before the `remark`, or make the `remark` longer or shorter (so that the `remark` doesn't end the page), it compiles.

The problem seems to have something to do with the way `eso-pic` handles color or includes `xcolor`, because:

- If I replace `\usepackage{eso-pic}` with `\usepackage{xcolor}` or `\usepackage{color}`, it compiles.
- But, if I replace `\usepackage{eso-pic}` with `\usepackage{background}`, it hangs.

Also:

- If I delete `\color{blue}` *or* the `\sectionrule` command in the `\sectionfont` command (or both), it compiles. (!?)

Obviously, if this is a one-off, I can tweak the pagination a little. But this is occurring in a long book with many `remarks`, many `\section`s, and many pages, so I'd like a more robust solution, if possible.

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine for me. (I tried both `a4paper` which has everything on one page and `letterpaper` which has the pagebreak exactly at the new section.)

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid of that. I'm using TeXShop 4.62 on Mac OS 11.2.3 (Big Sur). Anyone have a similar setup and can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Can you look at the `.log` file and indicate (1) which version of the TeX engine (something like `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2`) and (2) which versions of `eso-pic` and `xcolor` your are using?

Comment: `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`, `eso-pic 2018/04/12 v2.0h eso-pic (RN)`, and `xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)`

Comment: First, try updating to a current TeXLIve version. (TeXShop is just the frontend editor/previewer.) http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html My undestanding is that on Macs you can just download the installer for the new one, install it, and open up one of the configuration pages for MacTeX to switch to the new distribution. http://www.tug.org/mactex/multipletexdistributions.html

Comment: And after successfully installing the new version, if you want to get rid of the old version to save space, you just need to delete some files. http://www.tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html

Comment: Updating to the current TeXLive version solved the problem. Thank you! If you write it up as a short answer, I'll accept it.